# Disable Windows Network access for specific router LAN ports

Tags: windows, networking

Most modern routers support creating a "Guest" Wifi network to give Internet access to guests, while isolating them from the rest of the network, however the same is not possible for wired clients.

What would be the approach to achieve the same on a "per-(cable)port" basis? Let's say my router has 4 LAN ports, 3-4 are connected to Access Points that give Internet access to guests, how could I set this up so that those guests will be isolated away from the rest of the Windows Network? (LAN ports 1-2 + Wifi from the main router = Windows Network, Wifi from the APs connected to ports 3-4 should be isolated)

Comment: The switching portion of the all in one router would need to be VLAN aware and the router would need to support inter VLAN routing. It's not something you'd normally see on consumer grade all-in-one routers, but I believe aftermarket firmware (e.g. DD-WRT) can get that working...

Comment: Then let's say I have a modern Asus on dd-wrt with VLAN support, how would you go about doing that?

Comment: I'd suggest checking out the DD-WRT wiki to see if it's even possible based on your make and model as "Modern" does not necessarily equal "capable". http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Support#VL

Comment: How about Asus RT-AC68U (it supports VLAN VID/PRIO for fiber optic models) with merlin or tomato fws?